# Copying database with or without indexing on?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, indexing

This should really be a community wiki page, but I have to ask this question and see what I might be missing.  I'm a moderator on a site and they are going through a new site transition.

They started data migration yesterday around lunch.  It's still going on and they say it's going to take 30 more hours.  It's a rather large site (700 million records going from SQL Server to MySQL) but I couldn't fathom why it was taking so long.

I just found out that they're indexing on the fly.  Are there benefits to this?  Would it not be quicker and probably safer to copy and then index?  If anyone has links, I'll most likely choose that as the answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical procedure I know is to copy all the tables with disabled constraints and no indexes and recreate indexes from scratch afterwards and then enable the constraints. Rebuilding an index from scratch is **much** cheaper than creating it online during migration.

Googling a minute brought up this for you from the horse's mouth :) :

http://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/white-papers/mysql_microsoftsql2mysql_paper.pdf

see e.g. page 5:

> Also you'll want to take the
>   permissions and index statements from
>   the end of each of these files [the
>   generated MySQL DDL], and put them in
>   new files. If these statements are
>   left when migrating, migrating the
>   data will be significantly slower.

I didn't find a benchmark, but you could produce a very representative one yourself: Just migrate, say 1 million of your own records, using both strategies. The results should speak for themselves.

Here is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225993/importing-new-database-table).

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking.  Unfortunately since I'm only a mod, I have no say so in the matter.  Do you know of any benchmark testing sites that could show this?  I want to try and get them to stop what they're doing, change it, and then start over.  Might be able to cut that 30 hours down to 10 or less.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not in a position where I could do that.  But I do appreciate the link and the help.  Emailing it to them now.  Seeing if I can get them to stop the migration, edit the scripts, and then do these.  Doubt they will though.